# Java Regex - verify if string contains non-empty trimmed tokens separated by a period (.)

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex that is used to identify if a string contains non-empty tokens (after trimmed) separated by `.`, i.e., of the following form. This is the best I came up with.

```
Pattern.compile("^(?!\\.)(?!.*\\.$)(?!.*?\\.\\.)(?!\\p{Space}$)(?!\\p{Space}\\.)(?!.*\\.\\p{Space}$)[\\p{Graph}\\p{Space}]+$", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
```

The unit tests are present in the following code:
https://ideone.com/kuej3D

This works for all the cases. I, however, feel there is a better way of doing the same.

For example,

how to check formats of the form,

`<s1><.s2>*`

`s1` is a non-empty string after trimming the leading and trailing spaces.

`.` is the literal period

`s2` is a non-empty string after trimming the leading and training spaces.

`*` denotes that the number of occurrences can be minimum 0 and maximum infinite.

Ex:

`` alpha$#@.ksj`\\c.lijd*3260_+ `` is a valid string

`a b. c d. e f` is a valid string

`alpha.` is an invalid string

`.beta` is an invalid string

Empty string is an invalid string

is an invalid string

`x..y..z` is an invalid string

All the test cases in the above ideone code should print `true`.

Comment: How about https://ideone.com/nqTMLi

Comment: @Toto: Thanks. Last four tests fail with your pattern. Is there a way to handle them efficiently?

Comment: Well, I don't understand why `alpha.` is invalid (in the question) and `a.` is valid (in ideone).

Comment: @Oleg: Your pattern missed some results (false negatives). https://ideone.com/nTkoA4

Comment: @Toto `a. ` is surely invalid. The last test case in my ideone (https://ideone.com/kuej3D) is for this only.

Comment: Surprising! Why is it so?

Comment: @Oleg `find` can't be the solution here, as it may search within the string, while here the whole string has to match I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
"\\s*[^.\\s]+\\s*(\\.\\s*[^.\\s]+\\s*)*"
```

For trimming, it matches optional spaces in the beginning, before and after each dot and at the end. It might be easier to read without trimming:

```
"[^.\\s]+(\\.[^.\\s]+)*"
```

This pattern matches something that is not a dot and not a space, optionally followed many times by `.` and something that is not a dot and not a space.

Comment: Perfect! This is working. So, if I trim the string and use the second pattern it will still pass all the test cases, right?

Comment: @SaiNikhil No, use the first one. You also want to allow spaces in-between. If you trim the string, you may eliminate only the `\\s*` in the very beginning.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks 